# Loop nested within loop, but not recognising top level loop

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to use this code to produce one figure for EACH 'eventid' which represents the sum of 'bestOdds' divided by 100. To do this you need to sum the 'bestOdds' for EACH 'selection' within EACH 'eventid' and divide by 100. The problem with my code is that it sums the figures for ALL 'eventid's because it is not recognising my original for loop 'for event in eventid'.

**My code:**

```
>>> data1 = []
>>> for event in eventid:
... request2 = requests.get(f'https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=******************&eventId={event}&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
... json2 = request2.json()
... for selection in json2['selections']:
...     data1.append(100/selection.get('bestOdds')
...     sum(data1)
```

**Output of code:**

```
    111.63871382786564
    111.63871382786564
    111.63871382786564
    111.63871382786564
    111.63871382786564
    111.63871382786564
    111.63871382786564
    111.63871382786564
    111.63871382786564
    111.63871382786564
    218.69755411039012
    218.69755411039012
    218.69755411039012
    218.69755411039012
    218.69755411039012
    218.69755411039012
```

**What output of code should look like:**

```
111.63871382786564
111.63871382786564
111.63871382786564
111.63871382786564
111.63871382786564
111.63871382786564
111.63871382786564
111.63871382786564
111.63871382786564
111.63871382786564
107.058840283
107.058840283
107.058840283
107.058840283
107.058840283
107.058840283
```

See how the code sums for ALL 'eventid's instead of for EACH individual 'eventid'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to sum within each `event`, then you should initialize `data1` to an empty list inside your outer `for` loop, i.e.:

```
for event in eventid:                                                           
    request2 = requests.get(f'https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=****************&eventId={event}&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    json2 = request2.json()                                                     
    data1 = []                                                                  
    for selection in json2['selections']:                                       
        data1.append(100/selection.get('bestOdds'))                             
    print(sum(data1))
```

Now, as you iterate through the `eventid` list, you will store only the `bestOdds` for the current event and print the sum of those, rather than the sum of the odds for all events, as is the case if you initialize `data1` outside your outer `for` loop.